# Peek into gSuite drive users files

Tags: google-drive-api, google-workspace

I have a problem, where a former employee has filled up his gDrive way to much, as to have reason. The user is disabled, but we have to keep it deactivated for legal purposes, because we suspect ilegal content.
My question is if there is a way to peek into those files. Maybe list them only, without opening them. I tried googleing around but was not able to find ans answer to that.

Answer (score 0):

This types of questions are outside of the scope for Stack Overflow and (likely) no one here is qualified to tell you how to proceed.

If you suspect illegal content is being stored on said user, do not reactivate it or try to peek into the files without being explicitly instructed to do so by someone that has the knowledge to tell you if, when and how to do it in the eyes of the law.

Contact your legal department and ask for legal advice on this matter.

**This answer does not constitute legal advice or a legal opinion on any matter discussed.**

---

#### If you still want to do it...

You can:
- [Use Google Vault for Legal Hold](https://support.google.com/vault/answer/7657464?hl=en&ref_topic=3215535)

or

- Reactivate the user with a different temporary password and browse the files.

Comment: According to EU law, I am allowed to look into the data, since it is a business account. Some people tried to fight it, yet the employer was given the right to do it. 
I am not trying to spy on my employee, but to get a listing of the files. For his job description, there is no way in hell that he could have needed so much space.

Comment: Yeah, I'd still like to avoid that.

Comment: the vault might actually be an option